# How to transfer Access Oledb to C# windows form arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, oledb

Hi can anyone help me in regards to this.
I am making a hangman project.
But words should come from the Access oledb.
Can anyone give me an idea on how to do this.
I am using Office 2007 and VS 2010.

For me to replace this code:

```
public void text()
    {
        char[] divider = {','};
        string[] word = {"GENES","APPLES","GRAPES"}; //Words List replace    this with words from access oledb//
        words = new string[word.Length]; 
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (string a in word)
        {
                string [] splitter = a.Split(divider);
                words[counter++] = splitter[0]; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are using Office 2007 for what? Have you searched for "get records from access oledb C#"

Answer (score 0):

```
public void text()
{
     List<string> oWords =  new List<string>();
     string sConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=PathtoYourAccessDB.accdb";
     string sQueryString=  "select YourWordsColumn from YouAccessTable";

     using (OleDbConnection oConnection = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString))
     {
          OleDbCommand oCommand = new OleDbCommand(sQueryString, oConnection);
          oConnection.Open();
          using (OleDbDataReader oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader())
          {
               while (oReader.Read())
                     oWords.Add(oReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
          }
     }
     // If you want the words in an array
     string [] words = oWords.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for this i also want to ask how to do int when it comes to values being int instead of string?

Comment: @Mary List<int> myInts = new List<int>(); Then in the while loop to read the values from the reader,cast it to int like this while (oReader.Read())
                     myInts.Add(Convert.ToInt32(oReader.GetValue(0)));